# How can I extract polyline points in tmx map?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Information in map is :

```
     <objectgroup name="Waypoint" width="32" height="24">
  <object name="waypointsline" x="843" y="3">
   <polyline points="0,0 -13,130 -39,202 -69,237 -125,262 -162,295 -189,340 -184,376 -166,411 -124,453 -98,484 -78,529 -78,598 -80,659 -101,689 -200,695 -317,700 -453,696 -534,693 -566,656 -582,622 -585,563 -586,488 -577,428 -550,335 -547,284 -565,225 -599,190 -675,171 -751,164 -799,133 -829,93 -842,17"/>
  </object>
 </objectgroup>
```

How can I extract them in objective-C?

I tried:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *waypoints = [objects objectNamed:@"waypointsline"];
if(waypoints) {
    NSString* v = [waypoints valueForKey:@"waypointsline"];
}
```

And it returned nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polyline and polygon in TMX were introduced to cocos2d-iphone in version 2.0-rc0:

> [NEW] TileMap: polygon, polilines and gid are parsed from the objects (issue #1311)

If you are using newer version than 2.0-rc0, I guess you can access the points by something similar to:

```
CCTMXObjectGroup *objectGroup = [tileMapLayer objectGroupNamed:@"someGroup"];
NSMutableDictionary *waypoints = [[objectGroup objectNamed:@"waypointsline"];
NSString *v = [waypoints objectForKey:@"polylinePoints"];
```

For more details please refer to:

- [HOW TO: convert TMX polygon objects into box2d shapes for collision detection](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/28695) (look like the category implementations in this post can help with prior-2.0-rc0 versions)
- [cocos2d-iphone issue #1311](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=1311)
- [cocos2d-iphone issue #1311 change on GitHub](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/commit/59dcd3f75a8ced1b1e774259e54d9d57385f6d1d)

Comment: Well, I suppose my answer is a consequence of not having worked with Cocos2d... Good one! :-)

Comment: I edited the information in map, using your code, `[dict objectForKey:@"polygonPoints"];` returns nil.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `polylinePoints` for your case. I had a mistake :)

Comment: I just found my cocos2d version is 1.0.1, so it doesn't work. Thanks for your answer, I will try it later:)

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer accordingly. So you may need to upgrade your cocos2d before trying this. Be careful with the difference between versions: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:migrate_to_v2.0. I think parsing it as XML (like @Dr.Kameleon answered) would be a good choice at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in `XML` format, so all you have to do is parse that `XML`.

If it was for Mac OS X, I would suggest you went for `NSXMLDocument`, but since what you want is iOS-specific, then your next bet would `NSXMLParser`.

However, there still is an **easier approach**...

**Download this :** https://github.com/Insert-Witty-Name/XML-to-NSDictionary

**And then :**

```
NSDictionary *dic = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:myxml error:nil];
```

---

**UPDATE**

---

In order to get your XML string data :

```
NSString* filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"map" ofType:@"tmx"];
NSString* myxml = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath
                                            encoding:NSUTF8Encoding
                                               error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to ios and cocos2d programming, I wanna know if there's an easy way to do this, like use `CCTMXObjectGroup` or something.

Comment: @Arty the way I'm suggesting is **really** easy - all you have to do is include 2 files (available in the download link I sent you) and write just **one line of code**... :-)

Comment: Sorry for another problem: how can I get the `myxml`, I used `CCTMXTiledMap` to load the xml,,

Comment: @Arty where did you get that "information in map" you mentioned in your question? Is it in a file?

Comment: Yes, it's in a file named map.tmx, I used `self.tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"map.tmx"];` to load it, so I don't have the string.

Comment: Well, you **can** have the string though... check my updated answer. (you may then try the way I suggested you and use the `myxml` string there...)

Comment: Thanks, now I got some clue to parse xml files under mac:)